# Why SimpleGADriver's results depend on the initial design variables values?

Tags: openmdao

I am using SimpleGADriver to optimize a MIP problem with multiple constrains and objects for a spring design project. I have a question regarding the initial values of the design variables.

Based on my understanding of the Genetic Algorithm, I thought that the initial values of design variables should be generated randomly by the GA driver and what value I choose won't affect the results, however, the calculated object variables changed when I used a different set of initial values using `prob.set_val()`.

for example, if I set an "installation force" input variable to `F_input = 1200` the driver would give the object variable "working force(max)" around `F = 1500`, however, if I use `F_input = 4000`, I will get something like `F = 2300`. the results show that both runs comply with the constrains, the only difference is the maximazation quality, besides, both results are stable with the same initial values between multiple runs(the solver did converged at those points).

FYI, my solver setting is 10 bits for two continuous design variables and there are other three integer design variables, pop_size = 200, max_gen = 2000(which I set to a quite larege number to get stable results), crossover = 0.2, mutation = 0.02.

I did checked the OpenMDAO source code and found this in the genetic_algorithm.py:

```
   new_gen = np.round(lhs(self.lchrom, self.npop, criterion='center', random_state=random_state))
   new_gen[0] = self.encode(x0, vlb, vub, bits)
```

where the `x0` is the user defined initial value array.

My confusion is why the `new_gen[0]` need to be replaced by `x0` here, and if this is the reason for what I obseved that the results of the SimpleGADrive is initial value sensitive?

If this is how the SimpleGADriver works, dose that mean I need to give some sensible initial values for getting the optimal results?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenMDAO's `SimpleGADriver` is exactly that, a simple implementation of a GA. There are many more complex and subtle implementations out there. I wasn't the one who wrote that driver, and its been quite a while since we implemented it. So I'm going mostly off my interpretation of code, and augmented with a little bit of vauge memory of this topic.

The initial populations is mostly random. There is some ability to [specify a seed](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/drivers/genetic_algorithm_driver.py#L99-L102) if needed via an evironment variable. But other than that, it should be random. So I find it a little surprising that you're getting totally stable and reproducable results with giving one. It might be helpful if you could provide a simple test script that shows the behavior clearly.

Onto your core question now: Why does the driver replace the 0th population member with your initial condition? Because we believes that if the population was truely random then using the initial condition wouldn't hurt. If the user gave a meaningful condition though, adding it to the population is way of helping it along. So it seems like it shouldn't hurt and can only help.

The fact that you're seeing the final value change depending on the existence of that one initial population member tells me that you're likely not using a large enough population, or enough generations, or one of your mutation settings is too weak... basically you don't have your GA configured well enough to give a robust/consistent global optimum and you're effectively doing a semi-local search based on the initial population.

This is unfortunately a far to common problem with GA's. They are "global" in theory, but in practice the are more like "semi-global" or I think of them as more "exploratory". If you don't give them a large enough population (or otherwise tune the other various settings) they can still get stuck in a local optimum pretty easily.

My rough guess of what is going on here, without knowing anything about your problem (which is a HUGE caveat and very strongly limits the validity of this conclusion) is that your problem has a difficult design space... where there are many bad combinations and very few good ones. The random initial sample space is probably filled with VERY bad candidates. Your initial guess is likely to be the very best candidate by a large margin. Because of that, the algorithm is probably getting stuck on a local solution centered around whatever your initial candidate is.

You can very this by looking at the fitness scores of your entire gen 1 population and seeing if your initial value is in fact the very best by a large margin.